# Android Studio 3.0 Execution failed for task: unable to merge dex

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, build-error

android studio was getting build error while build execution with following:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex"

My app:build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pdroid.foodieschoice"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
        force 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1'
        force 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.1'
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1'
        force 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

any solutions

Edit: i have done with sample through firebase github site and solved

Comment: you have to include multiDex support in your app

Comment: and try cleaning, rebuilding your project

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and post the entire output of your Gradle console, not just that one line. The details of your problem lie elsewhere in the output.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have posted my entire error.. its just two line only.

Comment: That is not the entire output of your Gradle Console.

Comment: Try to disabled instant run clean your project and add  
android {
      defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        }
   }

Comment: any luck with this issue?

Comment: I added one dependency two times in my build.gradle. Remove one and sync the project will solve a problem.

Answer (score 67):

For Cordova based project, run `cordova clean android` before build again, as [@mkimmet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079113/android-studio-3-0-execution-failed-for-task-unable-to-merge-dex#comment88264694_47176418) suggested.

Comment: Someone please mark this answer right. It solves the problem.

Comment: For me, installing the 'cordova-plugin-androidx' and 'cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter' sovled the problem

Answer (score 59):

This error happens when you add an external library which may not be compatible with your `compileSdkVersion` .

Be careful when you are adding an `external library`.

I spent 2 days on this problem and finally it got solved following these steps.

- Make sure all your support libraries are same as `compileSdkVersion` of your `build.gradle(Module:app)` in my case it is `26`. [image]
- In your defaultConfig category type **multiDexEnabled true**. This is the important part. [image: multiDexEnabled True image]
- Go to **File** | **Settings** | **Build, Execution, Deployment** | **Instant Run** and try to Enable/Disable Instant Run to hot swap... and click **okay** [image: Enable Instant Run to Hot swap... Image]
- `Sync` Your project.
- Lastly, Go to **Build** | click on **Rebuild Project**.
- Note: **Rebuild Project** first cleans and then builds the project.

Comment: it is helpful me , Thank you.

Answer (score 51):

Try to add this in gradle

```
    android {
      defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        }
   }
```

Comment: Did you tried to invalidate cache in android studio? @Anguraj

Comment: Not the only step to enable multidex. Also not needed in newer API levels

Answer (score 29):

### Resolution:

Refer [to this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex): As there are various options to shut the warning off depending on the **minSdkVersion, it is set below 20**:

```
 android {
     defaultConfig {
         ...
         minSdkVersion 15 
         targetSdkVersion 26
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
     ... }

 dependencies {   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' }
```

If you have a **minSdkVersion greater than 20** in your build.gradle set use the following to shut down the warning:

```
  android {
      defaultConfig {
          ...
          minSdkVersion 21 
          targetSdkVersion 26
          multiDexEnabled true
      }
      ... }
```

Update dependencies as follows:

```
     dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
     }
```

Again the only difference is the keywords in dependencies:

minSdkVersion below 20: use **compile**

minSdkVersion above 20: use **implementation**

1. ***I hope this was helpful, please upvote if it solved your issue, Thank you for your time.***
2. ***Also for more info,*** on **why** this **occurs**, please read the first paragraph in the link, **it will explain thoroughly why?** and **what does this warning mean.**

Answer (score 24):

Simply try doing a "Build -> Clean Project". That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me in an Ionic/Cordova project by running *cordova clean android* while I also had cordova-android-support-gradle-release plugin installed.

Comment: Love it when something simple fixes things!! Thanks!

Comment: This fixed it for me when working with React Native.

Comment: Thanks, it's the easiest solution for this issue, I spent my 3 days to solve this issue and your answer solves my all problem.

Once again thank you my bro!!!

Comment: Thanks. Helped me on Android Studio 4.1. Saved my day.

Answer (score 7):

For me, adding

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' 
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
```

into the *app level Build.gradle* file solved the issue

Answer (score 6):

Go to your module level `build.gradle` file and add the following lines to the code

```
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

That solved the problem easily. Check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Answer (score 4):

Use  multiDexEnabled true as below.

```
{
 minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

this Solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I tried many solutions as mentioned above including the multiDexEnabled true but none of that worked for me.

Here is the solution which worked for me - copy this code in app\build.gradle file

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' && requested.name != 'multidex') {
            details.useVersion "${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to run gradlew clean before running the code

Comment: I changed minSdkVersion, it's enough

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me, figured out that I was in the middle of updating to AS 3.0.1 and after I did the update, cleaned and rebuilt the app, everything was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

For me what fixed this error was changing one line in my app's gradle dependencies.

**from this**:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+') {
    force = true
}
```

**To this**:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0') {
    force = true
}
```

Comment: Only that worked for me. I did not need to add 
force = true

Answer (score 1):

Also be sure your app is subclassing MultiDexApplication

```
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication

class App : MultiDexApplication()
```

or if not subclassing Application class, add to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
  android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me. clean prepare and run.

```
cordova clean android;
ionic cordova prepare andriod;
ionic cordova run andriod;
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the similar error.

> **Problem** :

[image]

> **Solution** :

Main root cause for this issue ismultiDex is not enabled.
So in the **Project/android/app/build.gradle**, ***enable the multiDex***

For further information refer the documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle

[image]

Comment: For me, just add the line         multiDexEnabled=true
in defaultConfig

Answer (score 0):

Are you in between SDK or platform updates?
If yes complete those completely and then try to continue. 
I normally update the individual packages that need to be updated as to taking the entire update which could go up to 2.5 GB sometimes. Doing this complete update sometimes fails. I had a number of SDK updates once I upgraded to Android Studio 3.0 and was getting the above error since all packages had not been updated. Once I updated all packages the above error was gone.

Comment: Hope you have cleared or invalidated your cache and restarted Android Studio ? For me Android Studio 3 seems buggy as compared to the previous versions.

Comment: anyone ever fix this? cannot get past it!

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing firebase library version from 2.6.0 to 2.4.2 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the use of Java 1.8 in a module, but not in the app module. I added this to the app build gradle and worked:

```
android{
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I have enabled multidex: 
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true

I have cleared cache, ran gradle clean, rebuild, make, tried to make sure no conflicts in imported libraries (Removed all transitive dependencies) and made all updates. Still:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

**Turns out the build did not like:
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.21'**

Answer (score 0):

When the version of Android Studio is 3.0.1, Gradle Version is 4.1 and Android PluginVersion is 3.0.0, it will encounter this problem. Then I downgrade Gradle Version is 3.3, Android Android is zero, there is no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this when requested SDK version didn't match the dependencies. You can click the line highlighted and fix this clicking the red light bulb. No need to find the actual version, just let the IDE figure it out for you. And add google repo to maven config.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error and in *my* case, the error was resolved when I fixed a build error which was associated with a different build variant than the one I was currently building.

I was building the build variant I was looking at just fine with no errors, but attempting to debug caused a `app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug` error. Once I switched to build the other build variant, I caught my error in the build process and fixed it. This seemed to resolve my `app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug` issue for all build variants.

Note that this error wasn't *within* the referenced external module but within a distinct source set of a build variant which referenced an external module. Hope that's helpful to someone who may be seeing the same case as me!

Answer (score 0):

I Have Done and fixed this issue by just doing this jobs in my code

Open ->build.gradle
Change value 
from

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1)Please add multiDexEnabled true
2)if you get compilation error then check your app level build.gradle weather same dependencies are implemented with different versions.
3)Remove one if you find same dependencies.
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {

```
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

```
hope it works fine :) Happy Coding
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to avoid suck kind of error is:

-Change library combilesdkversion as same as your app compilesdkversion

-Change library's supportLibrary version as same as your build.gradle(app)