# > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android

Hello to everyone and thanks in advance,although this question might be repeated but It is been more than 5 hours that I am not able to solve this problem, everything was working smoothly and fine , i din't face any bug or error before, I just don't know where this error came from ??
I closed the project when it was working fine, after opening it again , saw this error.
[image: execution failed]

I have searched a lot of websites to find the solution but tried everything,none of them worked for me, this problem has come out of no where.
Please help me.

Here is my build.gradle(Module:app) code.
[image]

[image]

and here is the build.gradle(project level) of my project.
[image]

as I mentioned,this code was perfectly working and even that time i uploaded the project copy to Google-Drive, after importing that too  i face this issue.

Comment: Take a look at this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html. For android prior to 5 you need to manage apk with a memory addressing more than 65k

Comment: @shadowsheep thanks for your comment but I have solved the question and i suggest you to look at it once to understand more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of struggling, I have finally solved this problem.

The problem mainly shows that the **External libraries are mixed** for this reason it might create bug and unsuccessful build. For more details, please check my answer in:
[Android Studio 3.0 Execution failed for task: unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079113/android-studio-3-0-execution-failed-for-task-unable-to-merge-dex/48531191#48531191)

I don't wanna delete the question because the solution which has worked for me may not work for some others, but trying every solution is a better way to understand the problems.