# Gradle dex issue when using support lib dependency v7:26.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hello I am having a problem with my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dell"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.3.0'
    implementation 'hanks.xyz:htextview-library:0.1.5'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Android Studio gives me this warning:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.0, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0 and
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0

Can somebody please help me? I don't know what to do. I tried even making it v 27. I even deleted it, but it still didn't solve my problem.

I am also seeing this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
> >     dex

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: the problem says that my recycle view is v7 27 and support is version 26,I don't know how to solve it

Comment: post your complete gradle file please

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque I have a new question if you could take a look I would be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Android Studio warning

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.0, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0 and
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0

#### Problem

One of your dependencies (`com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.3.0`) has a [transitive dependency](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#view-dependency-tree) on `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0`. Meanwhile, the support libraries that you manually declare in your build file use version `26.1.0`.

#### Solution

Update `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `27` and your support libraries to `27.1.1`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 27
        ...
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    ...
}
```

#### Tip (optional)

Since `com.android.support:design` has transitive dependencies on `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` and `com.android.support:support-v4`, you do not have to manually declare the `appcompat-v7` or `support-v4` dependencies *if* you declare the `design` dependency.

Comment: @ora This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079113/android-studio-3-0-execution-failed-for-task-unable-to-merge-dex

Comment: let me try I will let you know

Comment: It seems that one of the libraries you added uses a newer version of the recyclerview. Try updating your `compileSdkVersion` to 27, and all of your support library dependencies to 27.1.1.

Comment: I will try now and let you know

Comment: Also, you can remove the `appcompat-v7` and `support-v4` support library dependencies since the `design` library depends on those libraries (called transitive dependencies)

Comment: should I remove them both?

Comment: You can remove both. I edited my post with more info. I'm glad you got it working!