# Sometimes !transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex

I am using `implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'` dependency to implement in app purchase billing. but i am getting  `Unable to merge dex`

Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService

```
Error:Execution failed for task Execution failed for task app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug
 java.lang.RuntimeException com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException 
Unable to merge dex
```

Below is my `build.gradle` app level  file code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//def BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION = "8.5.1" //current version of butterknife
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}




android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.syncyes"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$project.versionName"
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:$project.versionName"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$project.versionName"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    // sinch audio calling
    implementation(name: 'sinch-android-rtc', version: '+', ext: 'aar')
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    //    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    // Multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    // RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'


    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"

    // firebase database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    // videocache
    implementation 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0'
    // InApp Billing
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
//    // firebase notification
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
//    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    // video compressor
    implementation 'com.github.WindSekirun:MediaResizer:1.0.0'
    // Dexter runtime permissions
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:3474549'
    // twitter sharing
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation('com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-auth-api-phone'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-auth'
    }
}
//    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION"

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is my project level `build.gradle` file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }


}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }



    }

    project.ext{
        myBuildToolsVersion="20.0.0" //String
        myMinSdkVersion=10 //Integer
        myTargetSdkVersion=22
        myCompileSdkVersion=27
//      ext.versionName = '27.1.1'
        versionName = '27.1.1'
    }


}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean the project, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for response but i have already tried. it doesn't works .

Comment: check this link once 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079113/android-studio-3-0-execution-failed-for-task-unable-to-merge-dex